# Sent emails never reach destination. ESM Message Tracking Center shows nothing after "Submitted to Categorizer"

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, message-queuing

A couple of users (out of 150) are experiencing an issue where they send out emails or message invitations, but they are never received by the recipients. When i go into Exchange System Monitor, and into the Message History for the email, it shows the status just stops after "SMTP: Message Submitted to Categorizer". the message just seems to disappear after this. It's only for a few users, and only on occasional emails.

details about our network, Exchange 2003, McAfee Virus Scanning on the computers (but email scanning is disabled), and we have an IronPort device doing email spam filtering, but i don't even see the emails showing in the message tracking on the IronPort, so it isn't even making it that far.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen messages "die" after being submitted to the Categorizer but I have to ask, what directories are you excluding from scanning on the Exchange server?

Comment: i don't see anything specifically being excluded, but i'm not the one who set up the scanner. though, from what i can see, the only thing enabled in the virusscan console is "On-Delivery Email Scanner", which i thought only scanned incoming items, not outgoing (I could be wrong about that though)

Comment: Take a look here to make sure that any file system or real time av scanners have the appropriate directories excluded on the Exchange server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823166